# props are passed but are undefined when they are mapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-props

When I map the array directly, I don't face any error but if I pass the same array through props, I face the error that "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

brands array

```
const brands = [
  {
    key: 1,
    Name: "Nike",
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    Name: "Adidas",
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    Name: "Apollo",
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    Name: "Puma",
  },
];

export default brands;
```

Parent Component

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";
import SimpleAccordion from "./simpleAccordion";
import "./Sidebar.css";
import brands from "./BrandNames";

function App() {
  console.log("I am in App component", brands);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="sidenav">
        <SimpleAccordion children="Categories" brands={brands} /> // here passing the props as brands
        <hr style={{ color: "#999999" }} />

        {/* <h1>Helooooooo</h1>
        {brands.forEach((brand) => {
          return <span>{brand.Name}</span>;
        })} */}

        {brands.map((brand, key) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{brand.Name}</h1>
              <h1>{brand.key}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <h1>Helooooooo</h1>
   <SimpleAccordion children="Brands" />
        <hr style={{ color: "#999999" }} />
        <SimpleAccordion children="Stores" />
        <hr style={{ color: "#999999" }} />
        <SimpleAccordion children="Price" />
  
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Child Component

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
 import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
 import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
 import {Checkbox} from '@material-ui/core';
 import brands from './BrandNames';


export default function SimpleAccordion(props) {
    
   const[iconName,setIcon]= useState(false);
  
   function handleClick(){
     setIcon(!iconName);
   }

// shows data at first time but then becomes undefine 
console.log("here", props.brands)  
  


    return (
      <React.Fragment>

// Directly mapping the  (imported)"brands" array, no error
          {brands.map((brand, key) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{brand.Name}</h1>
              <h1>{brand.key}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        
// mapping props.brands array and there are errors.
          {props.brands.map((brand, key) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{brand.Name}</h1>
              <h1>{brand.key}</h1>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <Accordion style={{boxShadow:"0px 0px 0px "}} >
          <AccordionSummary expandIcon={iconName ? <CloseIcon /> : <AddIcon/>} onClick={handleClick}>
            <Typography style={{color:"#333333",fontWeight:"bolder"}}>{props.children}</Typography >
          </AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails >
            <Typography>

            </Typography>
          </AccordionDetails>
          </Accordion>
         
          </React.Fragment>
    
  );
}
```

If I don't use the props in the child component, it works fine. brands.map works fine but when props are used, props.brands give the errors i.e TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Why are the props giving me the errors...

Comment: are you using `SimpleAccordion` anywhere else?

Comment: Use inspect option on chrome to see whether the brand prop is being passed or not

Comment: Yes, ```SimpleAccordion``` are being used like 4 times in the parent component.

Comment: They all expect a `brands` prop but you're only giving it to the first one. The rest will be trying to map `undefined` as the error says.

Comment: Props are indeed being passed but only at the first render the data is being shown after that it is undefined. I have console.logged the ```props.brands``` just above the return function in the child component.

Comment: I see, I should give the props to the other components as well !

Comment: or just check that `props.brands` is an array first before calling `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was rendering more than one `SimpleAccordion` component but only passing props to the first component. That's why the props were undefined when mapped as other components were not given the props.